# List names of boost named managed shared memory

Tags: c++, linux, boost, shared-memory

I am using boost managed_shared_memory. And I am creating by name.

E.g.: managed_shared_memory Segment(open_only, OneName);

And inside in an own segment I can list all existing objects (created by Segment::construct).

But is it possible to get a list of existing segments? (E.g. to avoid double naming...)

Such like (Pseudo):

```
boost::interprocess::list_existing_segments
```

If it is possible, please explain. If not, be so kind to confirm.

Greeting 
Earlybite

Answer (score 0):

> But is it possible to get a list of existing segments?

Given enough privileges, probably yes. However, that's not where Boost focuses (use tools like Process Explorer to inspect system details; on linux, `ls /dev/shm` usually helps). ¹

> (E.g. to avoid double naming...)

That's not viable, as at this point you'd only get a race. As soon as you "established" that a given name is not in use yet, it might simultaneously be created by one of the many other processes in the system. So the result of your check is useless.

You cannot hedge this by interprocess synchronization, because (catch-22) the same problem applies to the synchronization object used for that.

In short: You can only try the creation and notice that it failed.

---

¹ Likewise, Boost doesn't focus on lowlevel hardware access, instead abstracting a higher level interface that's portable

Comment: I think, that it is precise.

Comment: Still one further question: You also can use a memory address..., so what happens with the names (These must be stored anywhere, isn't it)?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean. Using memory addresses has nothing to do with shared memory. Shared memory does **not** need to have the same _base address_ in each process's _address space_. Yes, the kernel has these mappings, but that doesn't mean it must expose them to userland processes. Let alone that Boost Interprocess "must" expose this functionality.

Comment: IIRC you can create managed shared memory by name (managed_shared_memory Segment(open_only, OneName);) or by an address of the memory. But its equal for now... What I mean is, that boost knows if a segment exists, or not. So I think names must be stored somewhere, so...IMO there must be a possibility to list all existing segments.

Comment: You can only open by name. At the same time you can (unportably) _suggest_ a base address. It might work depending on address space layout on the particular platform (this is so you can sometimes use raw pointers in shared memory). Boost IPC solves it using `offset_ptr<>`

Comment: @Earlybite And come on. **YES**. Those mappings exist. Only they make zero sense in userspace (your question wasn't tagged [tag:linux-kernel]). What did you ask though? (did you try `ls /dev/shm/` already? It **is** that list). Boost just tells you the error it [gets from `mmap`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)